# mysql query for long records, taking long enough to show records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with around 500000 records, all I want to do is place a select query with LIKE wildcard using limit, no matter what I do, it takes long enough to show result. That's worth nothing for me, how can I make it run better? My query is below

**QUERY**

```
 if (isset($_GET['res'])) {
   $value = $_GET['res'];
   $val = explode(" ", $value);
      $query = "SELECT productid, productname, retailprice, lmnr, suplier 
                FROM comp where productname = '$value' ";
      $count = count($val);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
          $query .= " union Select productid, productname, retailprice, lmnr, suplier
                 from comp where productname like '%" . $val[$i] . "%' ";
      }
             $query .=" GROUP BY productid, productname, retailprice, lmnr, suplier LIMIT  $start, $limit";
 }
 $result_query = $db->query($query);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

> **NOTE**
>   I have broken this query into unions as it is used for searching purpose, I want to make query search from all possible matches of a string separating with SPACES i.e. A TEST QUERY. Shall be taken as '%A%', '%TEST%', '%QUERY%'

Comment: [mysql-indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Do you have an index on productname?

Comment: 500000 records with union / group by with where with LIKE %..% with limit, this will result in "Using temporary; Using filesort" with deepscans (read high start values) and most likly this generates an MyISAM disk based temporary table (what needs to by grouped on disk with quicksort algoritme what will be slow with readom i/o reads and writes) because most likly the result doesn´t fit in memory.. EXPLAIN statement will EXPLAIN it all...

Answer (score 0):

Talk about an insanely over-complicated query. why do you have to run unions all? Each query you add to the union is run as its OWN independent query, and then all the results are combined to form the final result set. Very painful. Why not

```
SELECT ...
WHERE (productname IN ($val1, $val2, $val3, etc....))
   OR (productname LIKE '%$val[1]%')
   OR (productname LIKE '%$val[2]%')
   OR ....
   etc...
```

still highly ugly, but at least it's just one SINGLE query. And of course, as always, we should point out that you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), using deprecated mysql interfaces, blah blah blah...

Answer (score 0):

Index the productname column. It is not a bad idea to have a separate column for keywords, so whenever the smaller column containing the keywords contains any of the keywords the database server does not have to search for them in the longer text.